Can we measure $c=1$?
Usually the speed of light is measured using the S.I. units, yielding a result in $m/s$.
In geometric/Planck/Natural units it is known that we take $c=1$.
Clearly this is just a redefinition of the units of measure.
I was wondering though if it is possible to construct an experimental apparatus that measures the speed of light directly utilizing, for example, natural units.
In this way the apparatus should measure exactly 1, with its relevant uncertainty, without never referring to the S.I. units.
Does this idea make sense at all?
Is it possible to make measures directly utilizing other types of units, like natural units?
(I am not referring to "obvious" different units like minutes instead of seconds or pounds instead of kgs and so on)

In natural units, measuring $c = 1$ would just mean that you verify light to have the same speed as itself, and it's not clear what that would even mean, experimentally. Maybe if you sent pulses of light through two identical fiber optic cables and found they arrived at the end at the same time?

You don't have to measure c at all. Instead you are defining either your time unit or your length unit through c and the other. "Natural units" are also just a choice, by the way, no different from meter, second and kilogram. They happen to optimize the appearance of our formulas. Other than that they aren't giving us much. The only numerical values that nature dictates and that are of any actual interest to us are the unitless numbers like the fine structure constant and things like muon/electron mass ration.

With the current definitions of the SI units, any proposal to "measure $c$" is tautological.  You build (or buy) an atomic clock to establish a time/frequency reference, then use light propogation distances and your clock to establish your meter.  Uncertainties in your measurement will be due to frequency uncertainty or instability in your clock, or due to uncertainty or instability in your secondary length reference — that is, maybe your carefully calibrated meter stick is undergoing thermal expansion or whatever.
Natural units are even simpler in the new post-2019 SI units, because the constants $c,e,\hbar,k,N_A$ are assumed to be constants of nature.  The macroscopic joule is now defined in natural units, as some annoying multiple of $\hbar$ and the standard cesium second.  If you like $\hbar c=1$, you are just defining $\rm 197\ MeV=1\ fm^{-1}$.
The "naturalness" that you want is really baked into the SI system itself.  The best example is probably the Josephson definition of voltage, where the potential across a superconducting junction driven with frequency $f$ takes on integer multiples of $hf/2e$.  We call them "natural" units because they appear in the nice expressions with integers. Even physicists can keep track of integers.

Imagine a place where gravity affects pretty much all aspects of life. People there think of vertical distance as a completely different physical quantity than horizontal distance. They can measure horizontal distance in kilometers and altitude in meters.
Figuring out a diagonal distance is complicated. There is this fundamental constant of the universe that relates vertical and horizontal distances.
$$C = 1000 \space m/km$$
The metric of space is given by $d = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + (z/C)^2}$.
Theoretical physicists sometimes work in natural units. They measure horizontal distances in kilemeters, and altitude in "altitude-kilometers". This makes $C = 1$. This is exact by definition. They do have to experimentally determine the length of an "altitude-kilometer".

Now imagine a $4$D spacetime where time affects pretty much all aspects of life. People there think of time as a fundamentally different physical quantity than distance. And it is. But there are relationships and similarities between space and time that classical physics would not lead you to expect.
Measuring an interval that includes both is complicated. People there measure distance in meters and time in seconds. There is a fundamental constant of the universe that relates time and distance.
$$c = 3 \cdot 10^8 \space m/s$$
The metric of spacetime is given by
$$s = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - (ct)^2}$$
Theoretical physicists sometimes work in natural units. They measure time in years, and distance in light-years. This makes $c = 1$. This is exact by definition. They do have to experimentally determine the length of a light-year.

We dont have to imagine your first scenario. Go onto the seas and the nautical navigation system is already like that. Even in SI units they would use kilometres for horizontal distances and metres for heights.

Nice world building. Is there a version of this that plays out inside a black hole?
